# What format does BigQuery timestamp take?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to input a timestamp type into BigQuery as a RFC3339 string:

```
"2019-07-25T11:07:41-04:00"
```

It doesn't seem to be working. What format does Timestamp type expect in BigQuery? The documentation doesn't specify input.

Comment: According to [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#timestamp-type), format is `YYYY-[M]M-[D]D[( |T)[H]H:[M]M:[S]S[.DDDDDD]][time zone]`. You're ok with what's required, weird that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a valid format for casting or coercion, but be mindful that leading and trailing whitespace (or whitespace before the timezone offset, which many systems add) will cause the coercion to fail.

I would suggest something along the lines of (using [`TIMESTAMP()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp)):

```
TIMESTAMP(TRIM(ts_string))
```

. . . or using [`CAST()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#casting):

```
CAST(TRIM(ts_string) AS TIMESTAMP)
```

If there's whitespace within the string, you could just replace it using [`REPLACE()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#replace):

```
TIMESTAMP(REPLACE(ts_string," ",""))
```

. . . or more thoroughly, replace all types of whitespace including tab using [`REGEXP_REPLACE()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_replace):

```
TIMESTAMP(REGEXP_REPLACE(" 2019-07-25T11:07:41 -04:00 ",r"\s+",""))
```

And see if that works for you. It may also be worth looking at the value in a hex or text editor where you can see if there are any hidden characters in the string.

If there are things you need to work around that don't play nicely with simple replacements, you can use [`PARSE_TIMESTAMP()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#parse_timestamp) and provide a pattern mapping the elements of the source string to a valid `TIMESTAMP`.

If you're still having issues, it would also help to know how you're trying to load this string—is this via an import/load job, or a SQL `INSERT` or `UPDATE`? Are you using the BQ console, API, `bq` command line tool, or a language-specific SDK? What's the source format of the data? All of these may be helpful clarifications on the question to get you a better answer. What error message are you being shown, and is it for a single value or all values?

It's possible that some of the values are in an invalid format and are causing the operation to fail. You could test this by importing a few rows of the data you know are in a valid format and seeing if you still get an error.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**Your input works fine for me. **