# Error inserting RFC3339 string into bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, timestamp, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have following `datetime` string `2020-03-30T16:26:37-04:00` and when i try to insert this in bigquery (i am sending string object as part of a json object) i get error

`Invalid datetime string "2020-03-30T16:26:37-04:00"` > 'invalid'`.

According to this post, i think the format is okay but i am still getting error

[What format does BigQuery timestamp take?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57205464/what-format-does-bigquery-timestamp-take)

- This is inserted from gcp-dataflow pipeline to bigquery
- I am using `apache-beam[gcp]==2.19.0` version

**Summary how i am inserting in BigQuery**

- I receive messages as byte stream from pubsub
- I have a decoder which decodes the bytestream to list of dictionary i.e.,`[{"field_one":value, "field_two":value_2}]`
- This dictionary is then sent to `bigquery`

Comment: To clarify, is this inserted from a Dataflow/Beam job ? If so which SDK and version ?

Comment: Can you add more information to your question? How are you trying to insert this data to BigQuery? Are you using Dataflow? If so,  can you share your pipeline and a sample of your data?

Comment: updated my question with answers.

Comment: As you can see here (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#datetime_type), dattime doesn support timezone. Can you try using timestamp instead?

Comment: @EmAe did it work for you?

Comment: actually, I haven't been able to modify my schema to deploy the changes i am working on. I have asked this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61018561/schema-modification-giving-partitioning-error

Comment: @EmAe I'll take a look. Just a question: do you need o use Terraform for that? Maybe you could try using bq commands for this specific task

Comment: Yeah. Our whole infrastructure is built using terraform. That's how we are managing it.

Comment: For this problem with DATETIME I'm sure this is the solution. Can I post it as an answer?

Comment: i haven't been able to verify it but you can put it as answer and i will accept it once i do verification

Comment: Posted. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#datetime_type), `DATETIME` type doesn't support timezone. 

The correct syntax is `YYYY-[M]M-[D]D[( |T)[H]H:[M]M:[S]S[.DDDDDD]]` where:

> YYYY: Four-digit year 
>  [M]M: One or two digit month
>  [D]D: One
>   or two digit day
>  ( |T): A space or a 'T' separator
>  [H]H: One
>   or two digit hour (valid values from 00 to 23)
>  [M]M: One or two
>   digit minutes (valid values from 00 to 59)
>  [S]S: One or two digit
>   seconds (valid values from 00 to 59)
>  [.DDDDDD]: Up to six
>   fractional digits (microsecond precision)

If you need timezone, consider using [TIMESTAMP](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#timestamp_type).

 For `TIMESTAMP` the syntax is `YYYY-[M]M-[D]D[( |T)[H]H:[M]M:[S]S[.DDDDDD]][time zone]` where:

> YYYY: Four-digit year
>  [M]M: One or two digit month
>  [D]D: One
>   or two digit day
>  ( |T): A space or a `T` separator
>  [H]H: One
>   or two digit hour (valid values from 00 to 23)
>  [M]M: One or two
>   digit minutes (valid values from 00 to 59)
>  [S]S: One or two digit
>   seconds (valid values from 00 to 59)
>  [.DDDDDD]: Up to six
>   fractional digits (microsecond precision)
>  [time zone]: String
>   representing the time zone. When a time zone is not explicitly
>   specified, the default time zone, UTC, is used. See the time zones
>   section for details.

Note that when inserting a new value to a timestamp field, the value will be converted to UTC.

I hope it helps