# Schema modification giving partitioning error

Tags: google-bigquery, terraform

I have previously created a table in bigquery using following script in terraform

```
resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "my-dataset" {
  dataset_id  = "datasetname"
  description = "description"
}

resource "google_bigquery_table" "mytable" {
  dataset_id = google_bigquery_dataset.my-dataset.dataset_id
  table_id   = "mytable"

  time_partitioning {
    type = "DAY"
  }

  schema = <<EOF
[
  {
      "name": "field_one",
      "type": "STRING",
      "mode": "NULLABLE"
  },
  {
      "name": "field_two",
      "type": "RECORD",
      "mode": "NULLABLE",
      "fields": [
          {
              "name": "sub_field_one",
              "type": "FLOAT",
              "mode": "NULLABLE"
          },
          {
              "name": "sub_field_two",
              "type": "FLOAT",
              "mode": "NULLABLE"
          }
      ]
  },
  {
      "name": "field_three",
      "type": "STRING",
      "mode": "NULLABLE"
  }
]
EOF

}
```

This worked fine and i was able to create `mytable` in bigquery. Now i have to modify this table and have to add a new value to it (`field_four`. So made this script

```
resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "my-dataset" {
  dataset_id  = "datasetname"
  description = "description"
}

resource "google_bigquery_table" "mytable" {
  dataset_id = google_bigquery_dataset.my-dataset.dataset_id
  table_id   = "mytable"

  time_partitioning {
    type = "DAY"
  }

  schema = <<EOF
[
  {
      "name": "field_one",
      "type": "STRING",
      "mode": "NULLABLE"
  },
  {
      "name": "field_two",
      "type": "RECORD",
      "mode": "NULLABLE",
      "fields": [
          {
              "name": "sub_field_one",
              "type": "FLOAT",
              "mode": "NULLABLE"
          },
          {
              "name": "sub_field_two",
              "type": "FLOAT",
              "mode": "NULLABLE"
          }
      ]
  },
  {
      "name": "field_three",
      "type": "STRING",
      "mode": "NULLABLE"
  },
  {
      "name": "field_four",
      "type": "RECORD",
      "mode": "NULLABLE",
      "fields": [
          {
              "name": "sub_field_three",
              "type": "STRING",
              "mode": "NULLABLE"
          }
      ]
  }
]
EOF

}
```

When i run it using `terraform plan`, it shows that the new field will be added. But when i do `terraform apply`, I get following error

```
Error: googleapi: Error 400: Cannot convert non partitioned/clustered table to partitioned/clustered table., invalid

  on filename.tf line 10, in resource "google_bigquery_table" "mytable":
  10: resource "google_bigquery_table" "mytable" {
```

I am not changing the partition of the table. Whats going on here. How to make schema change to

1. Add a new field?
2. Change the field type (which has only `null` values as of now) to something new?

Terraform details

```
Terraform v0.12.24
+ provider.google v3.1.0
+ provider.google-beta v3.1.0
+ provider.random v2.2.1
```

Comment: I reproduced your configuration files and could add a new field without problems.
About the second questions, it seems that you can't change your field's type usong Terraform. As you can see here (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/manually-changing-schemas#changing_a_columns_data_type), for changing a field's type you need a query job, which is not possible in Terraform as you can see in this open issue (https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/issues/5986)

Comment: Actually, now I could reproduce the same problem as you, but for that I had to remove    "time_partitioning {
    type = "DAY"
  }" 
from your first code. Are you sure that you used this exact code when you created the table?

Comment: Yeah, pretty sure. I just checked the partition using this command `SELECT * 
  FROM \`project_id.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS\`
` and all i see is `NO`

Comment: So i think the problem is that previously table wasn't created as parittioned (not sure how). Can i change the table to a partitioned tabled now? Do i need a specific column to partition the table?

Comment: You can't change that in the table, but you can create a partitioned table from query in your current table using bq command. About your fields, it depends: if you want a partition by ingestion time, you' ll not need any field like that. If you want to partition by some field, you'll need a DATE or TIMESTAMP field to create the partition

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#creating_an_ingestion-time_partitioned_table_from_a_query_result

Comment: So from terraform documentation (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/bigquery_table.html) `time_partitioning` only supports `DAY` type and `field` is optional. If `field` is missing, it will create partition per day based on load time. Now, I don't understand that why the table wasn't created with partition even though my terraform had it specific properly.

Comment: the point is that even without a field, the table should have been created as a partitioned table if you put the DAY argument. The difference is that the partition would be based on the time of load and not on a column.

Comment: could it be a terraform bug?

Comment: For me your code worked normally. I reproduced it on Terraform 0.12.24 for Linux. Can you try running your first code again to test if the same stuff will happen?

Comment: so i think the issue was with terraform. The previous table was created with `terraform v 0.12.20` i guess. Now when i created with `v.12.24`, I can see partition column named `_PARTITIONTIME` in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` for my table. I have also verified adding new columns once the table was created with correct partition.

Comment: Great @Em Ae. Is there something left to be discussed in this question?

Comment: not really. as usual, you can post your finding and i can accept that as an answer.

Comment: Posted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reproducing the same codes I could add a new field without problem. As discussed in the comments, the error below is raised when you try to transform a non partitioned table into a partitioned table. In this case, the problem was caused by a version mismatch of `Terraform`: the version used to create the table didn't support partitioned table so a normal table was created. When running both codes in Terraform 0.12.24 it worked.

```
Error: googleapi: Error 400: Cannot convert non partitioned/clustered table to partitioned/clustered table., invalid

  on filename.tf line 10, in resource "google_bigquery_table" "mytable":
  10: resource "google_bigquery_table" "mytable" {
```

About the second question, you can't change your field's type using Terraform. As you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/manually-changing-schemas#changing_a_columns_data_type), for changing a field's type you need a query job, which is not possible in Terraform as you can see in this [open issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/issues/5986).

I hope it helps